# XSD: Test in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I got an XML schema that contains something like the below lines.

What do these test lines mean?
Do they somehow describe a document?

```
...
<xs:element name="Document" 
            type="BaseDocument">
  <xs:alternative test="(@doc_face eq 'init') 
                        and 
                        (@doc_op eq 'included')" 
                  type="SystemInit"/>
  <xs:alternative test="(@doc_face eq 'Z')" 
                  type="Zreport"/>
</xs:element>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are (as Alexander Petrov has already pointed out) type alternatives in an XSD 1.1 schema.  The `test` attributes are evaluated in order:

- If the `Document` element has `doc_face` and `doc_op` attributes with the values 'init' and 'included', respectively, then the first test evaluates to true and the governing type of the `Document` element is the type named `SystemInit` in the default namespace (or with no namespace value, if there is none).
- Otherwise, if the `Document` element has a `doc_face` attribute with the value 'Z', then the governing type of the `Document` element is the type named `ZReport` in the default namespace (or with no namespace value, if there is none).
- Otherwise (i.e. if none of the alternative tests evaluates to true), the declared type of the element, here `BaseDocument` in the default namespace (or none) becomes the governing type of the `Document` element.

Comment: what does governing type mean?

Comment: The *governing type* of an element is the type against which it will be validated.  In the simple case, it will be the declared type, i.e. the type specified in the relevant (i.e. governing) element declaration; in more complicated cases, the governing type may be selected by conditional type assignment (as here), or by an xsi:type specification in the document instance.

Answer (score 1):

See [Type Alternatives](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).

> Type alternatives can be used by an Element Declaration to specify a condition ({test}) under which a particular type ({type definition}) is used as the ·governing type definition· for element information items governed by that Element Declaration.